# Отключить swipe в slick слайдере после клика

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Вот инициализация слайдера миниатюр

```
    $(".miniature_slider").not(".slick-initialized").slick({
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        speed: 1000,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        vertical: true,
        asNavFor: $(".big_slider"),
        focusOnSelect: true,
        verticalSwiping: true
    });
```

При клике на слайд происходит автоматический свип на первый. Как отменить этот свип?

Как работает слайдер можно посмотреть на этой верстке [карточка товара с слайдером](https://postolenko.github.io/evenlours_card/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Не особо понял но попробуй infinite: false это типа отключает переключение первому или последнему слайдеру

Comment: Пробовал все равно скролит.

Comment: Вот по этой ссылке можно посмотреть слайдер     https://postolenko.github.io/evenlours_card/index.html